# Go: multiple keys to single value in map

Tags: go

Is it possible to include an OR operator in the key of a map? Eg.

Go:

```
var a = map[string]int{
    "A1"|| "B1": 1,
    "A2": 2,
}
```

Error:

```
invalid operation: "A1" || "B1" (operator || not defined on string)
```

Comment: Do you want to set both `"A1"` and `"B1"` to `1`? Why not do so explicitly?

Comment: you mean include a separate line for each key?

Comment: Yes. `"A1": 1, "B1": 1, ...`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot. The grammar is defined at http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals and does not include this feature. You will have to specify each key distinctly.